# Dynamically add values to dynamic key in mutlidimensional associative javascript object

Tags: jquery, arrays, object

I give up searching!

I want to create an object in Javascript, that on the change of form fields, is populated with an ID as the first level, and a name - value pair as the second.

```
var ch = {};

    $('.trackchanges').change(function() {
        var id = $(this).parents('form').attr('id');
        var name = $(this).attr('name');
        var value = $(this).val();

        ch[id] = {};
        ch[id][name] = value;
    });
```

The code above, does not work. Every time it runs through the code, the value is reset.  I assume this has something to do with the need to use some sort of push `ch.push(key->value)`.

Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sample HTML**

This HTML includes two forms to demonstrate that the JavaScript solution (below) won't cause change conflicts across forms.

```html
<form>
    <input name="foo" class="trackChanges" />
    <input name="bar" class="trackChanges" />
    <input name="bof" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

<form>
    <input name="foo" class="trackChanges" />
    <input name="bar" class="trackChanges" />
    <input name="bof" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**The JavaScript (using jQuery)**

```js
$(".trackChanges").on("change", function(event) {
    var input = $(this),
        form  = input.parents("form"),
        data  = form.data("changes") || {};

    // log new change
    data[input.attr('name')] = input.val();

    // save changes
    form.data("changes", data);
});

$("form").on("submit", function(event) {
    var data = $(this).data("changes") || {};
    console.log(data);

    // just output the changes for now
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/naomi/6Dypg/1/)

---

I thinks this is a better solution because it bind the changes to each form using [`jQuery.data`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) and then you can recall that information at any time.

This means you don't have to do any sort of change tracking with a form's ID

---

Trying to lead by example here, so I'm going to address this:

> I assume this has something to do with the need to use some sort of push `ch.push(key->value)`

The problem with your code above doesn't have anything to do with `[].push`. The most glaring mistake of your code is that each time the `onchange` event gets fired, you're running this bit of code

```
ch[id] = {};
```

This essentially nukes the previous change that have been saved.

Comment: I think this is a better idea as well!  I will try it and let you know :)

Comment: Can you explain to me what this does? `data  = form.data("changes") || {};`  What is `.data("changes")` ?  This worked PERFECTLY but I want to know why :)

Comment: It's assigning `form.data("changes")` to `data`, but if it's blank (or undefined), it will assign an empty object (`{}`)